# Why this following Iterator turning into an infinite loop even thought it has a return statement in it?

Tags: java

Here is the method that I wrote that turns into an infinite loop printing "Same Pinch...!!!" endlessly: (right after the print statement, I have a return statement which should end the method after printing "Same Pinch...!!!" one time.

```
public boolean contains(Object input) {
    if(input == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    AIterator<R> myAsetIterator = (AIterator<R>) this.iterator();
    //use checkType(o) here in if statement and work from there please
    while(myAsetIterator.hasNext()) {
        indexToRemove++;
        if(input.equals(myAsetIterator.next())) {
            System.out.println("Same Pinch...!!!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is it's tester method. It's just a part of the main method.

```
private void testConstruction() {
    System.out.println("\nTesting Constructor");
    System.out.print("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    temp.add("Butterfinger");
    temp.add("Milky Way");
    temp.add("Kit Kat");
    temp.add("Three Muskateers");
    temp.add("Three Muskateers");

    Aset s3 = new Aset(temp);
    test(s3.getCapacity() == 10,
         "new Aset(temp) should return a capacity of 10: " + s3.getCapacity());
    test(s3.size() == 4,
         "size should return 4: " + s3.size());
    test(s3.toString().equals("<Butterfinger, Milky Way, Kit Kat, Three Muskateers>"),
         "toString should return\n        "+
         "\"<Butterfinger, Milky Way, Kit Kat, Three Muskateers>\":\n       " 
         + s3.toString());

}
```

Comment: How do you know it's an infinite loop?

Comment: Because I have this as a part of my project and eclipse is raising hell when I compile my project with this added line of code:     temp.add("Three Muskateers");

Comment: What does "eclipse is raising hell when I compile my project" mean?

Comment: Means what I typed in my question. An infinite loop of "Same Pinch...!!!"

Comment: Well, your problem definitely isn't in `contains`.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuild it, and see if it solves it.

Comment: Perhaps you are calling `contains` in an infinite loop.

Comment: The problem might be that a function is repeatedly calling contains: contains returns correctly but then is called again and again, making it look like it is looping when in fact something else is. Try putting a breakpoint where your print statement is and then add some more further up the call stack.

Comment: You might always want to consider whether your AIterator is correctly advancing through your items. If it never goes past the first item despite calling next() then contains will loop forever.

Comment: Like others have said there does not appear to be a problem with the listed code. We either need more code or you should just step through the code to see where it is looping, more likely recursion that it should not be.

Comment: iterator() is calling the constructor of AIterator class, which is resetting index to 0 every the iterator() is called. Thanks everyone. :)